# Купюроприемник + монетоприемник cashcode на delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, платежные-терминалы

На данный момент купюроприемник CashCode SM подключен к программе написанной на delphi. Все работает хорошо, купюры принимает.

Подключили монетоприемник NRI G13 для CashCode.

Вопрос: в модуле указаны разрешенные купюры, а как добавить разрешение на **монеты**?

```
const
  POLYNOM = $08408;

  //2 бит - 10 рублей
  //3 бит - 50 рублей
  //4 бит - 100 рублей
  //5 бит - 500 рублей
  //6 бит - 1000 рублей
  //7 бит - 5000 рублей

  B10   =   4;  //00000100
  B50   =   8;  //00001000
  B100  =   16; //00010000
  B500  =   32; //00100000
  B1000 =   64; //01000000
  B5000 =   128;//10000000

type
  Tnominal = record
    B10:Boolean;
    B50:Boolean;
    B100:Boolean;
    B500:Boolean;
    B1000:Boolean;
    B5000:Boolean;
  end;
```

Не посредственно сама функция с установкой принимаемых купюр

```
function TCashCodeBillValidatorCCNET.EnableBillTypes(
  Nominal: TNominal): Boolean;
var
  BillTypesByte:Byte;
begin
  try
   if not FComConnected then raise Exception.Create('COM порт закрыт, выполнение команды RESET не возможно');

   BillTypesByte:=0;

   // Установим биты купюр
   if Nominal.B10 then BillTypesByte:=BillTypesByte+B10;
   if Nominal.B50 then BillTypesByte:=BillTypesByte+B50;
   if Nominal.B100 then BillTypesByte:=BillTypesByte+B100;
   if Nominal.B500 then BillTypesByte:=BillTypesByte+B500;
   if Nominal.B1000 then BillTypesByte:=BillTypesByte+B1000;
   if Nominal.B5000 then BillTypesByte:=BillTypesByte+B5000;

   //Рубли хранятся в третьем байте

   SendPacket($34,[0,0,BillTypesByte,0,0,0]);
   ProcessMessage(206,'->ENABLE BILL TYPES');
   ProcessComand();

   if FData[0] = $FF then
   begin
     ProcessMessage(202,'<-NSC');
     raise Exception.Create('Получен отрицательный ответ (NAK)')
   end;

   if FData[0] = $00
   then ProcessMessage(203,'<-ASC');

   result:=true;
  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      ProcessMessage(104,E.Message);
      result:=false;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: А что говорит документация на монетоприемник? Неужели там не описан механизм взаимодействия, API ?

Comment: К сожалению, в документации путного найти ничего не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Монеты в связке NRI G13 для CashCode не выключаются / не включаются програмно и падают в мешок - только тумблером на монетнике. Ловить их сразу STATE_STACKED = 0x81.

Обработка "купюры в третьем байте" не верна!

Сначала получи список купюр по команде 0x41

```
b'\x02\x03}\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01RUS\x01\x05RUS\x01\x01RUS\x02\x05RUS\x02\x01RUS\x03\x05RUS\x03\x01RUS\x00\x02RUS\x00\x05RUS\x00\x01RUS\x01\x02RUS\x02\x02RUS\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01BAR\x00~g'
```

их 24 всего, у меня заполненны 13.

Потом по этому списку формируй команду 0x34 в ней первые 3 байта это битовая маска с 23 по нулевую позиции на ВКЛЮЧЕНИЕ-ВЫКЛЮЧЕНИЕ номиналов. Следующие 3 байта это позиция банкноты на удержание.

Рекомендую на команду 0x34 слать "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF". Это разрешит приём всех монет (всеравно контролировать их можно только выключателем на монетнике), а купюры будут в позиции `escrow` и принимать её или нет можно динамически.